# How to convert datetime to week range in stored procedure for grouping purposes

Tags: sql, sql-server

e.g.

```
Date | Name

1/1/13 | John

1/3/13 | Mary

1/5/13 | Joe

1/8/13 | Mary

1/9/13 | Bob
```

create additional column 'week range' in the resulting recordset using stored procedure that will look like this:

```
Date | Name | Week Range

1/1/13 | John |  12/31/2012 to 01/06/13

1/3/13 | Mary |  12/31/2012 to 01/06/13

1/5/13 | Joev |  12/31/2012 to 01/06/13

1/8/13 | Mary |  01/07/2013 to 01/13/13

1/9/13 | Bob  |  01/07/2013 to 01/13/13
```

I need to do this in order to group by week and display in a graph with correct series labels.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [Date],
       [Name],
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(day,1-DATEPART(weekday,[Date]),[Date]),3)
       + ' to '
       + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(day,7,DATEADD(day,1-DATEPART(weekday,[Date]),[Date])),3)
FROM   Table
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with following query. I have used BirthDate as a Date column.

```
SELECT   BirthDate,Name,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, BirthDate)-1), BirthDate))  + ' to ' + 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, BirthDate)), BirthDate)) WeekRange    
FROM Employee
group BY BirthDate, DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, BirthDate)-1), BirthDate),DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, BirthDate)), BirthDate),FirstName
ORDER BY BirthDate
```